# How php knows which cookie it will be using?

Tags: php, session, cookies

My conception might not be right,but how a website(using php) konws which cookie it should be using?

Compared with session,it has its tmp folder where all the session files are localed,php can use a session file by using sessionID , function session_id('xxxxxx'),it is clear and centain.Unlike session,cookie does not has cookie id,so how exactly does php knows which cookie it should be using?There are many cookie in the client.Or maybe php does not have a choice,it has to use the cookie which the client has sent to the server?Which means it is the client's decision to determine which one the php should be using?

Comment: The cookie is sent to the server as part of the request, and cookies for all sub/domain names that match the domain of the webserver are included in the request. PHP doesn't even know that a cookie exists until the webserver tells it

Comment: It's very clear,thanks